# Preview Content of Text Files inside Zip Files in Windows 10 File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

If I view a folder of text files using Windows Explorer in Windows 10 the Preview Pane on the right shows the contents of the current file whose name the cursor is over. However, if I view the contents of a zip file containing text files in Windows Explorer, then the Preview Pane is empty. Even if I use a zip file in which the contents have not been compressed (e.g. `7z a a.zip -mx0 *.txt`) then the Preview Pane still shows nothing.

Is there some way of getting the Preview Pane to work with zip files? (Alternately, if there is an alternative to Windows Explorer that can do it that would be ok.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in WinZip.

Open the Zip file, select all the text files, right click and choose "View files with internal viewer".

A new window will popup showing the contents of the text file, and you can use the arrow keys to move between files.